# How to check when the functions initiated by the loop have completed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loops

I am running `match()` to loop through an array or stop ID's. For each stop ID I am calling a function which loops through another array of route ID's and through the response of the AJAX call to find a match.

If it finds a match between the routeID and the RouteID in the array then it adds the result to another array in each loop.

My problem is that I can't find a way to determine when the functions called by the match() loop are complete.

The reason I need to do this, is that I need to make sure that the `jpFromStops` array is complete and ready to be processed by another function.

What is the best way to do this?

```
   function match() {
        // Array length is 5
        for(i=0; i < fromStopsAr.length; i++) {
            getFromRoutesStopId(fromStopsAr[i]);
        }
        console.log("Match Array Output: " + jpFromStops.toString());
    }

function getFromRoutesStopId(id) {
   jpFromStops=[];
   tempAr = [];

  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'http://apu-url.com/v1/gtfs/routes/stopid/'+id+'?api_key=API_KEY',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    cache: false,
    crossDomain: true,
    processData: true,

    success: function (data) {
    $.each( matchRoutes, function(index, value) {
      $.each(data.response, function(key, data) {
          if(data.route_short_name.toString() == value) {
             jpFromStops[jpFromStops.length] = id + ":" + value;      
          }
      });   
     }); 
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert("There is a problem");
    }
  });
}
```

Console log Output:

```
Match Array Output: 
jp-main.js (line 177)
2
115
jp-main.js (line 199)
2
113
jp-main.js (line 199)
2
087
```

Comment: add a counter which increments on success or error, and when it matches `fromStopsAr.length`, your done.

Comment: @brso05 How would I do that as I call the 'getFromRoutesStopId(id)' multiple times.

Comment: @Ted Would that counter be on the close of the success block on the Ajax call?

Comment: @Yonkee -- see jcubic's answer. It's better/

Comment: @brso05 I don't think async:false is supported by JSONP and cross domain calls.

Comment: @Ted Your answer worked fine. I just added the below [code]  matchLoopCnt ++;
  if(matchLoopCnt == fromStopsAr.length) { 
   console.log("Math Route Output: " + jpFromStops.toString());
  }[code]

Comment: @Ted Post that as your answer and I will accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a counter...sort of like:

```
var count = 0;
function getFromRoutesStopId(id) {
   jpFromStops=[];
   tempAr = [];

  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'http://apu-url.com/v1/gtfs/routes/stopid/'+id+'?api_key=API_KEY',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    cache: false,
    crossDomain: true,
    processData: true,

    success: function (data) {
    count++;
    if(count == fromStopsAr.length){your code or function call}
    $.each( matchRoutes, function(index, value) {
      $.each(data.response, function(key, data) {
          if(data.route_short_name.toString() == value) {
             jpFromStops[jpFromStops.length] = id + ":" + value;      
          }
      });   
     }); 
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      count++;
      if(count == fromStopsAr.length){your code or function call}
      alert("There is a problem");
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return promise and use $.when

```
function match() {
    var promises = [];
    // Array length is 5
    for(i=0; i < fromStopsAr.length; i++) {
        promises.push(getFromRoutesStopId(fromStopsAr[i]));
    }
    $.when.apply($, promises).then(function() {
        console.log("Match Array Output: " + jpFromStops.toString());
    });
}

function getFromRoutesStopId(id) {
   jpFromStops=[];
   tempAr = [];

  return jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'http://apu-url.com/v1/gtfs/routes/stopid/'+id+'?api_key=API_KEY',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    cache: false,
    crossDomain: true,
    processData: true,

    success: function (data) {
    $.each( matchRoutes, function(index, value) {
      $.each(data.response, function(key, data) {
          if(data.route_short_name.toString() == value) {
             jpFromStops[jpFromStops.length] = id + ":" + value;      
          }
      });   
     }); 
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert("There is a problem");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, However even using this, I still get the 'Match output' as empty, before the ajax updated the array.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with `ajax` calls, you need wait until each of them has finished the execution.

Follow this pattern:

```
var jobs = [11, 12, 14, 15];
function doTheJob() {
    if (jobs.length === 0) {
        alert('All jobs are done now.');
        complete();
        return;
    }

    var job_Id = jobs.pop();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/DoTheJob",
        complete: function () {
            doTheJob();
        }
    });
};
```